# should articles be added when explaining abbreviations

Tags: articles, usage

I wonder are the sentences below grammatically correct if we omit the articles?

> RPG stands for (a) ''role-playing game''

> RPG, also known as (a) ''rocket-propelled grenade''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are giving the long version of an abbreviation, there should be no article before it:

> RPG stands for "role playing game".

"A/an" refers to an actual thing, not the name or definition. So if you say, "*RPG stands for **a** role-playing game*", I will think, "Which role playing game does RPG stand for?"

Your second example sentence is not an explanation of the letters in the abbreviation, but explaining what an RPG *is*, so you should include an article before *both*:

> **An** RPG, that's to say, **a** rocket propelled grenade...

(BTW, I replaced "*also known as*" from your second example sentence because that phrase introduces an *alternate* way of saying something, like an abbreviation or nickname, never the full, normal name. A rocket-propelled grenade is *also known as* an RPG, not the other way around. On the other hand, the phrase, "*that's to say*" usually introduces an easier term to understand, or *a more standard way* to say something.)

Answer (score 1):

AME speaker, I would omit the "a" in both cases, they sound very jarring to me as-is.

You would not expect an "A" before "Role Playing Games" in the following example. And I see no reason to have them in your exemplars either.

```
Role Playing Games developed a dedicated following in the 70s and 80s.
```

Comment: "*Do you want to play **a** role playing game?*"

Answer (score 1):

> RPG stands for (a) "role-playing game."
>
> RPG, also known as (a) "rocket-propelled grenade."

Those sentences are wrong. The article "a" is not needed.

> RPG stands for "role-playing game."
>
> RPG, also known as "rocket-propelled grenade."

Those sentences are correct.